# C++ static array initiation: does inline initialization reserve space?

Tags: c++, arrays, static, avr, volatile

In C++, are the following two declarations equivalent?

```
static volatile uint16_t *ADCReadings = (uint16_t[64]){0};
```

or

```
static volatile uint16_t ADCReadings[64] = {0};
```

I'm reserving space for a buffer used inside and outside an ISR on AVR. But, though it would be interesting, I'm not looking here to know if this is the best way to do it - I'm wondering what the differences (if any) between the two declarations are, so that I can understand this better.

I do know that the two different declarations produce different sized binaries, so the compiler *appears* to be treating them differently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Are the following two declarations equivalent?

No. `(uint16_t[64]){0}` is a temporary array (a compound literal*), and if you try to compile the first line, you'll get a self-explanatory warning/error:

> `warning: temporary whose address is used as value of local variable 'ADCReadings' will be destroyed at the end of the full-expression` (Clang)
>
> `error: taking address of temporary array` (Gcc)

So, in the first line `ADCReadings` becomes a dangling pointer. Using it as a pointer into a buffer invokes undefined behaviour.

Gcc manual [reads](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Compound-Literals.html):

> In C, a compound literal designates an unnamed object with static or automatic storage duration. In C++, a compound literal designates a **temporary object that only lives until the end of its full-expression**. As a result, well-defined C code that takes the address of a subobject of a compound literal can be undefined in C++, so G++ rejects the conversion of a temporary array to a pointer.

---

> Is this true even at global scope?

Gcc and Clang don't produce warnings/errors in this case. Gcc manual further reads:

> As an optimization, G++ sometimes gives array compound literals longer lifetimes: when the array either appears outside a function or has a const-qualified type. ... if `foo` were a global variable, **the array would have static storage duration**. But it is probably safest just to avoid the use of array compound literals in C++ code.

So it seems that at the global scope `ADCReadings` won't be dangling.

> I do know that the two different declarations produce different sized binaries

In the first case, the compound literal array goes into the `.bss` section, and `ADCReadings` goes into the `.data` section:

```
0000000000004040 l     O .bss   0000000000000080     ._0
0000000000004010 g     O .data  0000000000000008     ADCReadings
```

`ADCReadings` is a pointer to `._0`.

In the second case, `ADCReadings` goes into the `.bss` directly:

```
0000000000004040 g     O .bss   0000000000000080     ADCReadings
```

This also translates into how `ADCReadings` is used. The following simple function:

```
uint16_t* foo() {
    return ADCReadings;
}
```

compiles into:

```
push   rbp
mov    rbp,rsp
mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rip+0x2ed8]        # 4010 <ADCReadings>
pop    rbp
ret
```

and

```
push   rbp
mov    rbp,rsp
lea    rax,[rip+0x2f08]        # 4040 <ADCReadings>
pop    rbp
ret
```

---

* [Compound literals](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Compound-Literals.html) are not part of the standard C++, some compilers (Gcc, Clang) allow them as an extension.

Comment: Is this true even at global scope? It certainly makes sense to me - but my compiler is not warning.

Comment: @user12049104, expanded my answer.